# PyQGIS non-vector Output Parameters

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

For any vector output, we can include a `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink` in the `initAlgorithm` definition. Is there a way to do this with generic filetypes? I have a script that will create a lookup table that needs to be exported as a CSV to feed into PowerBI.

This is what I have tried:

```py
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer('Network', 'Road Network', defaultValue=None, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer('RoutesLayer', 'Routes Layer', defaultValue=None, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterCrs('OutputCRS', 'Output CRS', defaultValue='EPSG:7855'))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('OUTPUT', 'Output Layer', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('csvOutput', 'CSV Output', QgsProcessing.TypeFile))
```

The last line creates an output field when you run the script but it will attempt to save it in a GIS layer format.

Is there a way to set the output as a specific filetype that is not a GIS layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit: [QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination.html)

This can be implemented in the `initAlgorithm` definition as so:

```py
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination('csvOutput', 'CSV Output', 'Comma Separated Values (*.csv)'))
```

When a temporary output is used (i.e. the user chooses not to specify an output file), the lines added using the `file.write` function are not stored and disappear at the completion of the script.

From this point, I used the parameter as if it was a standard text output in Python:

```py
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    ...
    csv = open(parameters['csvOutput'], 'w')
    csv.write('RouteID,LINK-DIR,SEQ')
    ...
    csv.close()
```